# Write to the middle of a binary file; using tellg() to find length?

Tags: c++

Okay so the code below is supposed to open a binary file, and write something to the middle element (in this case, the middle Student). My biggest question is, how do I find the "length" that I am trying to implement in my code? because right now it says the length is 0, and I need that length to change based on how big the file is.

edit. Oh and I want the length to be in terms of amount of 'Students'

Any input is appreciated, thanks.

```
 struct Student{
char Name[20];
int Age;
float GPA;
};


int main(){
Student A;
Student B;
Student C;
fstream out1("Test.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
out1.write((char*)&A, sizeof(Student));
out1.write((char*)&B, sizeof(Student));
out1.write((char*)&C, sizeof(Student));

Student objRead;
fstream in("Test.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
in.seekg(0, in.end);
int length = in.tellg();
in.seekg(0, in.beg);
cout << length;
in.seekg(((length/2)-1)*sizeof(Student), ios::beg);
in.read((char*)&objRead, sizeof(Student));
in.close();
```

Comment: Try to close ``out1`` before opening file for reading. Or try to call ``out1.flush()`` after write operations.

Answer (score 0):

So I answered my own question... In case anyone is wondering. I had to close out, thanks for that input, and then divide the total size by the struct Student. (:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Student{
int Age;
float GPA;
};
int main(){
Student A;
A.GPA = 4.0;
A.Age = 3;
Student B;
B.GPA = 4.0;
B.Age = 5;
Student C;
C.GPA = 4.0;
C.Age = 3;
fstream out1("Test.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
out1.write((char*)&A, sizeof(Student));
out1.write((char*)&B, sizeof(Student));
out1.write((char*)&C, sizeof(Student));
out1.close();

Student objRead;
fstream in("Test.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
in.seekg(0, in.end);

int length = in.tellg();
int reallength = length / sizeof(Student); 
in.seekg(0, in.beg);
cout << reallength;
in.seekg(((reallength/2)-1)*sizeof(Student), ios::beg);
in.read((char*)&objRead, sizeof(Student));
in.close();

Student temp;
fstream out("Test.bin", ios::out |ios::in| ios::binary);
out.seekg((reallength - 4)*sizeof(objRead), ios::beg);
out.read((char*)&temp, sizeof(Student));
out.seekp((reallength - 4)*sizeof(objRead), ios::beg);
out.write((char*)&objRead, sizeof(Student));
out.seekp(((reallength / 2) - 1)*sizeof(Student), ios::beg);
out.write((char*)&temp, sizeof(Student));
out.close();
```

}